# Temporarily disable keymap in vim

Tags: vim

I've got the following keymap in vim:

`inoremap { {  }<Esc><BS>i<CR><CR><Esc>ki<Space><Space>`

If I want to type a literal `{` without the other characters, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to enter a literal character in vim is to use `Ctrl-V`.

In your case, when in insert mode, you'd type `Ctrl-V` followed by `{`

Answer (score 2):

Note also that there exist several brackets oriented plugins that detect the context in order to not expand things like `{` in comments or string contexts. [lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets), that I'm maintaining, also has a enabled/disabled feature, toggled on the trigger key.

Otherwise, for the punctual disabling that doesn't match recognisable contexts there is `CTRL-V` as ffledgling has told you.

NB: the idea behind context detection is to match the result of `synIDattr(synID(line('.'),col('.')-1,1),'name')` against `'comment\|string\|character\|doxygen'` (see `lh#map#*context*()` functions in lh-brackets), and have your `map-<expr>` expand to either `{` or `{}` + cursor movement that doesn't break redo + other things possibly.